# Apache POI header.xml Docx output issue

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am new to Apache poi. I am using apache poi version 3.10 and java 1.6.

When I download docx file, I should get file with watermark. After downloading, when I try to open this docx, it gives me the error:  “The Office Open XML file cannot be opened because there are problems with the content” and in the description: text/xml declaration can only appear at the very beginning of the input. Location word/header4.xml

However, when I open docx viewer from browser, it perfectly shows me file with content, header and watermark.

Couldn't understand what gives error

```
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
headerFooterPolicy.createWatermark("Watermark");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
document.write(baos);
PortletResponseUtil.sendFile(request, res, outputFile,
baos.toByteArray(), contentType);
```

I tried this links
[Add watermark in word document using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248276/add-watermark-in-word-document-using-apache-poi)
[Add a watermark with Apache POI to a docx that already have a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864650/add-a-watermark-with-apache-poi-to-a-docx-that-already-have-a-header)
[Is it possible for Apache POI to add / remove watermark to Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192947/is-it-possible-for-apache-poi-to-add-remove-watermark-to-microsoft-word)

What I expect that I could open docx file with watermark in word document.

Comment: Office applications can usually open "corrupted" files and fix them on the fly. Apache poi can usually not open such files correctly. In those cases, it helps to open the file in word/excel and just save it again. Afterwards apache poi should be able to open the file

Comment: Problem is that I cant open file, When I try to open, immediately appears this error

Comment: [Apache POI 3.10 was released in 2014](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.10-FINAL) - what happens if you upgrade to a version that isn't nearly a decade old?